# Calculate difference of subsequent images in a collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, loop, change-detection

how do I call a Specific Image inside a Collection, to loop over it?

this is for calculating the difference of images for each set of two subsequent images in a collection

```
dImage= Image(t=i+1)-Image(t=1)
```

First problem Solved,
I now got the List with the Gradient. But how do I pick an image from that List?

```
Map.addLayer(ic_grad.get(1), {},'ic')
```

returns an error:"Cannot add an object of type  to the map."

normaly adding a calculated Image to the Map is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the backward difference in a ImageCollection by converting it to a list and mapping over that:

```js
var ic_list = ic.sort('system:time_start').toList(ic.size())
print(ic_list)

// calculate "backward" gradient, i.e. Tn+1 - Tn. Reverse get indices to get "forward" gradient.
var ic_grad = ic_list.slice(0,-1)
  .zip(ic_list.slice(1))
  .map(function(f) { 
    return ee.Image(ee.List(f).get(1)).subtract(ee.Image(ee.List(f).get(0)))  
   })

print(ic_grad)

// add image from list to map
Map.addLayer(ee.Image(ic_grad.get(1)), {},'ic')
```

Adapted from an [answer on the GEE developer forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-earth-engine-developers/AVEVg1PieMo).

Comment: I now got the List with the Gradient. But how do I pick an image from that List? ;     Map.addLayer(ic_grad.get(1), {},'ic') returns "Cannot add an object of type <ComputedObject> to the map."

Comment: You need to typecast the list element to an image: `Map.addLayer(ee.Image(ic_grad.get(1)), {},'ic')`